# Firebase: Storing a document ID within document itself while pushing as a Map

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

So I am taking some user input in a FORM.

e.g. fields are `[_name, _category, documentID]`

Once the form is submitted, data is pushed to Firebase in form of Map like this;

```
final dbRefItem = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("items");

 myMap = {
        "name": _name,
        "category": _category,
        "docReference":  //need doc ref here
      };

dbRefItem.add(myMap);
```

Now, once this Map is submitted to Firestore, it is given a random ID: I want this random ID to be pushed together in the `myMap` at `"docReference"` field.

I understand that the document isn't created yet so there may not be way to fecth it. But then maybe I can decide what reference I can push `myMap` with so I can store it in the field itsef.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The random IDs assigned by Firestore are generated in the client app.  You can generate a reference with a random ID by simply calling [doc()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference/doc.html) with no arguments.

```
final docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("items").doc();
```

Then you can put the [id](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/id.html) of the [DocumentReference](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference-class.html) in the map:

```
myMap = {
    "name": _name,
    "category": _category,
    "docReference": docRef.id
};
```

Then write the document using [set()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/set.html):

```
docRef.set(myMap);
```

Comment: if you add .doc() to docRef then it becomes a document reference not collection reference. And you can't add a MAP to doc.ref without specifying ref ID in "docRef.set" statement. So when I tried your method, it says
"'CollectionReference' is not a subtype of type 'DocumentReference'"

Comment: I'm not adding doc() to docRef.  I'm making a new ref and assigning it to docRef.  This code compiles fine for me.  I suggest rechecking what I've done here.  It's quite different than what you started with.

Comment: I checked, failed. Cold booted the entire app and now it seems to work! Bloody Brilliant! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
let id = 34234fdsf6hfgf //some random id
final dbRefItem = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("items").doc(id);  //your id here

 myMap = {
        "name": _name,
        "category": _category,
        "docReference":  id
      };

dbRefItem.set(myMap);
```

It will save your document with the custom id

1. To generate a custom id see uuid npm package

Comment: Adding .doc() to collection reference makes it a document reference itself hence can not add more document to same without defining it in dbRefItem.set(myMap);
The ID needs to be provided while pushing somehow!

Answer (score 0):

by calling the then() function after adding, you can get the id because the id was created.
you can access the id by the value and update the document you created.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdjjF.png)